# Chrome - JSON object statements unusual behaviour in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm playing with JSON objects in the Chrome console and I came across this unusual behaviour:

```
> {a:1}
1
> {"a":1}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
> b={a:1}
Object
> b={"a":1}
Object
```

Why does the first statement return 1 instead of an object, and why does the second statement work? I expected the first two statements to return the same output as the last two statements.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as a JSON object statement. In a JavaScript program, `b={"a":1}` is object literal notation resulting in a JavaScript object structure... not JSON data. The notation used looks similar, but the resulting data is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript expression statement can not start with a `{` because it would cause an ambiguity for the interpreter, which could also see it as a statement block.

So this is considered a statement block with a statement label and a numeric literal instead of an object literal:

```
{a:1}
```

But this is considered a statement block with invalid syntax, since there's no statement that can begin with `"a":`

```
{"a":1}
```

But these don't start with a `{`. They start with the `b =` so the `{` is considered to begin the object literal.

```
b = {a:1}
b = {"a":1}
```

> **[12.4 Expression Statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.4)**
>
> NOTE **An *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a Block**. Also, an *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with the `function` keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a *FunctionDeclaration*.

---

This means that all you need to do is start the expression statement with a different character to make it valid.

For example, you could wrap it in parentheses, and it will work:

```
({"a": 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that in the first scenario

```
> {a:1}
```

The curly braces are being ignored, and the `a` is interpreted as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

You get the same value `1` by simply typing

```
> a:1
```

If this is correct, the second example doesn't work because double quotes aren't acceptable characters in a label.

The third and fourth examples work, because they are valid variable assignments, and the console understands the objects as objects.

Comment: it is indeed seen as a label

Answer (score 1):

Chrome evaluates console input like this:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
    <your code here>
};
```

This leads to the `{` `}` brackets seen as extra block scope bracket and therefore getting ignored

Which then leads us to

`a:1` // 1

Seen as a label

And

```
a={a:1}
```

as correct assignment

Edit:

This is also what JSLint says on this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/amudus/1/edit)